# Create a data array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, datatable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDTPD.png)

I have a table of numbers and need to search for the month and the year of a given number and return a number for the given month and year in the table as shown in the picture then code it in vb.net
I'm quite new to programming, do you have any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to write a double for loop to populate a 2d array but I can't get the for loop inside a class.

Should I declare every single value of the table by hand or could I use a for loop? What else should I know to create a data table?

This is my code:

```
Public Class BarCodeNum
    Public Table(12, 9) As Decimal

    For i = 0 To 12
    For x = 0 To 9
    Select Case i
    Case 0
                    Table(i, x) = 202 & x
                Case 1
                    Table(i, x) = x & 37
                Case 2
                    Table(i, x) = x & 38
                Case 3
                    Table(i, x) = x & 39
                Case 4
                    Table(i, x) = x & 40
                Case 5
                    Table(i, x) = x & 73
                Case 6
                    Table(i, x) = x & 74
                Case 7
                    Table(i, x) = x & 75
                Case 8
                    Table(i, x) = x & 76
                Case 9
                    Table(i, x) = x & 77
                Case 10
                    Table(i, x) = x & 78
                Case 11
                    Table(i, x) = x & 79
                Case 12
                    Table(i, x) = x & 80
            End Select
    Next
    Next
```

Comment: Fir the record, when you upload an image and it enters the default text "enter image description here", you're supposed to enter the image description there. It's generally considered good etiquette to tell people where a link leads if you expect them to click it.

Comment: *"I cann't get the for loop inside a class"*. Of course you can. You write a method, e.g. a constructor, and you put the code there. You can't have anything but declarations at the class level so, other than code used to initialise a declared field, all code has to go inside a method. You call the method and the code gets executed. That's pretty fundamental to pretty much any programming language, so you might need to go back to basics.

Comment: If you don't need the loops to actually calculate the values, you can just initialise the array where you declare the variable, e.g. `Private matrix(,) As Integer = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} }`.

Comment: Are you REQUIRED to use a 2D array? You are using the words "array" and "table" interchangeably, but they are not the same thing. What are the actual requirements of your assignment? Most likely, though, this assignment was already due a long time ago...